# Get the 11.04 Ubuntu icon back

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, icons

I really liked the Ubuntu icon on 11.04.  Is there any way I can get that back in 11.10?

[image]

Comment: A link to the image would suffice. Depending on the icon in question (it might be possible)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that (move the main lens icon from the launcher to the panel) because it's location is (like everything else in the unity desktop environment) hard-coded.